# MYSQL to MSSQL migration

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008, migration

I have to move a MYSQL Database to MSSQL. I'd like to know if there's a tool that could automate this process a bit, at least for the tables and views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/?) (its free) can export the tables etc from MySQL.  You would just have to tinker with the create sequence in text editor after to make sure that you have the appropriate create sequence for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

MS SSIS can be used for MySQL to MSSQL data migration. Not surprisingly the tool fails to move data in the opposite direction. MS is all about you moving to their product from other products, but not moving from their product to another.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MySQL migration assistant from MS:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6f14640-da22-4604-aaaa-a45de4a0cd4a&displaylang=en

But the most effective way i have found (for structure and data) is to use mysqldump to tweak to actually ouput scripts sensible for SQL Server for importing.  However a little footnote, SQLCMD doesn't like large files without GO statements in them, so i wrote a little utility to inject GO statements for every 500 rows or so in the mysqldump generated files.